# How to get cart values when not Able to pass Parameters 

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using PayPal. I'm sending values to PayPal, and then getting values back. I'm not able to pass parameters because PayPal knows nothing about them.  How can I get the cart values in my method without passing the parameters?

I'm able to get the values like this

```
public ViewResult Index(Cart cart, string returnUrl)
{
    return View(new CartIndexViewModel
                    {
                        Cart = cart,
                        ReturnUrl = returnUrl
                    });
}
```

but, what if I'm not able to pass the (Cart cart) as a parameter - how do I get the values?

```
 public ViewResult Index()
    {

//what do i need to do here???

        return View(new CartIndexViewModel
                        {
                            Cart = cart,
                            ReturnUrl = returnUrl
                        });
    }
```

thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: In what scenario is it imposible to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: i'm uploading values to paypal and they are sending back a response. in my method I'm trying to get the values from "Cart" which is stored as a session. so, the user leaves the site, then is redirected. so paypal know's nothing about the "Cart" object

Comment: Not sure why this was pointed down ,but it would be great if who ever did would leave a comment to give me a chance to improve the question.

Comment: It's most likely voted down because no one sees a use for this question

Comment: Does paypal not reply with an id that you pass it, so you pass a cart id and find the cart, or order id and find the order and hence the cart?

Comment: Not voted down yet, but as of now your question is "please give me a value for my parameter" (answer for that is 42) without any information why any particular value should be chosen.

Comment: You must be reading a book by Sanderson and Freeman? The book says, that it's nice to store user Cart to Session, cause it's naturally valid only within session. And to let mvc engine extract Cart object from views they make a custom model binder, implementing IModelBinder,thanks to which you can add a parameter of Cart type to your Index action method. The approach written in that book works (or they'd never publish it; I tested it myself not long ago). Have you somehow changed that algorythm?

Comment: My question makes it quite clear why I downvoted this.  If you redirect users to another website, and then they are redirected back, you should keep some session id, and store the cart locally, to retrieve it through it's session id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could drop cookies that store the `Cart` data for that session. Then after you get a post back from paypal or whatever you could read the cookies from the user's request.

However I would think you could save the pending transaction to the database, send whatever data it is you send to paypal, and use a key or whatever method they have to link the paypal transaction to the pending transaction in the database. This would be more secure.

I'm sure paypal has a simple and well documented transaction process, that I would look into before trying either of these.

If your actually trying to integrate with paypal and not just using that as an example, here is a tutorial for [Paypal and MVC3](http://www.arunrana.net/2012/01/paypal-integration-in-mvc3-and-razor.html).

From [PayPal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted):

> **Relationship Between Express Checkout and Shopping Carts**
>
> If you do not
>   have your own shopping cart and have not integrated Express Checkout
>   with your website, you might consider using a third-party shopping
>   cart. A shopping cart is software that lets buyers put items in a
>   basket and calculates totals during checkout.
>
> PayPal partners with a wide variety of shopping carts, all of which
>   are PayPal compatible and provide secure purchases for your buyers.
>   The shopping cart vendor provides instructions for integrating their
>   shopping cart on your website. See the PayPal Partner Directory
>   (https://www.paypal-marketing.com/emarketing/partner/directory/directory.page?type=Shopping+Cart#mode=dir&dir%5Bops%5D=either&dir%5Bkey%5D=Keyword+term&dir%5Btyp%5D%5B%5D=1&dir%5Bind%5D%5B%5D=0&dir%5Brod%5D%5B%5D=1&dir%5Brod%5D%5B%5D=2)
>   for available shopping carts.
>
> IMPORTANT:If you choose a shopping cart, do not contact PayPal. PayPal
>   has no authority over a shopping cart vendor and cannot help you
>   resolve issues that might arise from the integration with or use of a
>   third-party shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

The controller probably had some trouble model binding the Cart.   How did you invoke this action?  What's the url?   maybe use fiddler or something to see what's being passed in.   Also, What's the Cart members?